# dask install error :ImportError: cannot import name 'compute'

Tags: python

Installed dask in vitualenv  jupyter notebook, but got following error:

[image]

so far tried :
`!pip install "dask[dataframe]"`
`!python -m pip install "dask[dataframe]" --upgrade`
`!python -m pip install "dask[complete]"`  none of above seems working